# add event listener click when element is not iset javascript

Tags: javascript

I have buttons that are added after the AJAX request, and I need to attach an `onclick` event listener on them before they are created in DOM. In JQuery, I used:

```
$("body").on("click", ".element", func);
```

In vanilla js, I wrote,

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  let el = e.target;
  if (el.classList.contains("icon-btn")) {
    el.classList.contains("active")
      ? el.classList.remove("active")
      : el.classList.add("active");
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

The problem is that `e.target` can be a children element, and that does not work.

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML.

Comment: Why can't you add the event listeners after the AJAX call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.closest()`

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var element = event.target.closest('.icon-btn');
  if (element) {
    console.log(element);
    alert('I am the element you are looking for');
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
}

div.icon-btn div,
div.icon-btn {
  border-color: green
}
```

```html
<div>
  Negative
  <div>
    Negative
    <div class="icon-btn">
      Positive
      <div>
        Positive
        <div>
          Positive
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      Negative
      <div>
        Negative
        <div>
          Negative
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        Negative
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```